# Rename all columns from a table within SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a SELECT query which references the same table several times. It basically goes to the Orders table and cross-references fields against the Users table to get the information.

```
SELECT o1.orderid,
       o1.productname,
       u1.*,
       u2.*,
       u3.*
FROM   orders o1
       INNER JOIN users u1
               ON o1.customer = u1.username
       INNER JOIN users u2
               ON o1.supplier = u2.username
       INNER JOIN users 3
               ON o1.manufacturer = u3.username
```

u1, u2, u3 will all return the same fieldnames. I actually want u1 to return its columns with a prefix of "customer", and u2 to return its columns with a prefix of "supplier" and so on.

So I end up with for example:

```
u1.AddressLine1 AS 'CustomerAddressLine1'
u2.AddressLine1 AS 'SupplierAddressLine1'
u3.AddressLine1 AS 'ManufacturerAddressLine1'
```

I don't want to write code like the above for each column, it would take way too long. Is there an easy way to rename them all in one go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no automatic way to do this.  However, you can generate the code rather easily.

For example:

```
select '      u1.'+column_name+' as customer_'+column_name+','
from Information_Schema.columns
where table_name = 'users' and schema_name = 'dbo';
```

You can then copy the results into your query.

Answer (score 1):

Not in SQL there isn't. Just write a macro in your favourite editor to write the "AS" part.

re: I don't want to write code like the above for each column, it would take way too long.

This is what software engineering is all about. Getting it right.